Query list of computers and export DNS servers to CSV
I am trying to query a list of servers and export the DNS servers to a spreadsheet. If I run the following command against one server, I get access denied:
Get-DnsClientServerAddress -CimSession server-name -InterfaceAlias ethernet -AddressFamily IPv4 |ForEach-Object ServerAddresses
Get-DnsClientServerAddress: server-name: Cannot connect to CIM server. Access is denied.

I assume I will need to run this using Invoke-VMScript but I need help obtaining a readable CSV output. I'm looking for something like this:
SERVER NAME     DNS SERVERS
server-1        10.0.0.1
server-1        10.0.0.2
server-2        10.0.0.1

How can I query a list of computers to find their DNS servers and export them to a CSV file?
I have this code that I use for querying services but I don't know how to modify it to get DNS servers:
$user = 'domain\username'
$pwd = 'password' | ConvertTo-SecureString -Force -AsPlainText
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential($user, $pwd)

$code = @'
$obj = New-object PSObject -Property @{
  Name = 'Service does not exist'
  Status = 'Not Installed'
}
$service = Get-Service -Name SERVICE -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if($service)
{
  $obj.Name = $service.Name
  $obj.Status = $service.Status
}
$obj | ConvertTo-Csv
'@
Get-VM -Name (Get-Content -Path "C:\folder\server-list.txt") -PipelineVariable vm |
ForEach-Object -Process {
  $o = Invoke-VMScript -VM $vm -ScriptText $code -ScriptType Powershell -GuestCredential $credential
  $o.ScriptOutput | ConvertFrom-Csv | 
  Select-Object -Property @{N = 'VM'; E = { $vm.Name } }, Name, Status
} | Export-Csv -Path "C:\folder\server-results.csv" -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture



query a list of servers and export the DNS servers

Use Invoke-Command with the -ComputerName parameter to pass the $machineList. Utilize Get-Credential to input credentials at runtime instead of embedding a password in the script. Pass the $cred to the -Credential parameter to define the security context for executing commands on the remote machines.
Note: I'll assume you have exporting to CSV handled and any necessary service existence conditions within the script blocks covered. However, I'm happy to assist with trivial adjustments if needed.
PowerShell - Variation 1
$cred = Get-Credential "domain\username";
$machineList = Get-Content -Path "C:\folder\server-list.txt";

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $machineList -ScriptBlock {Get-DnsClientServerAddress -AddressFamily IPv4} -Credential $cred | 
    Where-Object {$_.ServerAddresses.Count -ge 1} | 
        ForEach-Object {
            $serverName = $_.PSComputerName;
            $_.ServerAddresses | ForEach-Object {
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                'Server Name' = $serverName;
                'DNS Server'  = $_;
                }
            }
        };

Output
Server Name  DNS Server 
-----------  ---------- 
homicide002  10.105.50.15
homicide002  10.105.51.15
homicide002  10.105.51.10
gangunit001  10.105.50.15
gangunit001  10.105.51.15
gangunit001  10.105.51.10

PowerShell - Variation 2
$cred = Get-Credential "domain\username";
$machineList = Get-Content -Path "C:\folder\server-list.txt";

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $machineList -ScriptBlock {Get-DnsClientServerAddress -AddressFamily IPv4} -Credential $cred | 
    Where-Object {$_.ServerAddresses.Count -gt 0} | 
        Select-Object @{n="Server Name";e={$_.PSComputerName}}, @{n="DNS Server";e={$_.ServerAddresses}};

Output
Server Name  DNS Server                             
-----------  ----------                             
homicide002  {10.105.50.15, 10.105.51.15, 10.105.51.10}
gangunit001  {10.105.50.15, 10.105.51.15, 10.105.51.10}

PowerShell - Variation 3
$cred = Get-Credential "domain\username";
$machineList = Get-Content -Path "C:\folder\server-list.txt";

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $machineList -ScriptBlock {Get-DnsClientServerAddress -AddressFamily IPv4} -Credential $cred | 
    Where-Object {$_.ServerAddresses.Count -gt 0} | 
        Select-Object @{n="Server Name";e={$_.PSComputerName}}, @{n="DNS Server";e={$_.ServerAddresses.split(',') -join '; '}};

Output
Server Name  DNS Server                           
-----------  ----------                           
homicide002  10.105.50.15; 10.105.51.15; 10.105.51.10
gangunit001  10.105.50.15; 10.105.51.15; 10.105.51.10

PowerShell - Variation 4
$cred = Get-Credential "domain\username";
$machineList = Get-Content -Path "C:\folder\server-list.txt";

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $machineList -ScriptBlock {Get-DnsClientServerAddress -AddressFamily IPv4} -Credential $cred | 
    Where-Object {$_.ServerAddresses.Count -gt 0} | 
        Select-Object @{n="Server Name";e={$_.PSComputerName}}, @{n="DNS Server";e={$_.ServerAddresses.split(',') -join ', '}};

Output
Server Name  DNS Server                           
-----------  ----------                           
homicide002  10.105.50.15, 10.105.51.15, 10.105.51.10
gangunit001  10.105.50.15, 10.105.51.15, 10.105.51.10

PowerShell - Variation 5 (with unavailable)
$ErrorActionPreference = "stop";
$cred = Get-Credential "domain\username";
$machineList = Get-Content -Path "C:\folder\server-list.txt";

foreach ($machine in $machineList) {
    try {
        $dnsResults = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $machine -ScriptBlock {
            Get-DnsClientServerAddress -AddressFamily IPv4} -Credential $cred | 
                Where-Object {$_.ServerAddresses.Count -ge 1} | 
                    ForEach-Object {
                        $serverName = $_.PSComputerName
                        $_.ServerAddresses | ForEach-Object {
                            [PSCustomObject]@{
                                'Server Name' = $serverName
                                'DNS Server'  = $_
                            }
                        }
                    }
        if($dnsResults) {$dnsResults | Select-Object -Unique 'Server Name', 'DNS Server'}
    } catch {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'Server Name' = $machine
            'DNS Server'  = 'Unavailable'
        }
    }
};

PowerShell - Variation 6 (with unavailable)
$ErrorActionPreference="stop";
$cred = Get-Credential "domain\username";
$machineList = Get-Content -Path "C:\folder\server-list.txt";

foreach ($machine in $machineList) {
    Try { Invoke-Command -ComputerName $machine -ScriptBlock {
            Get-DnsClientServerAddress -AddressFamily IPv4} -Credential $cred | 
                Where-Object {$_.ServerAddresses.Count -gt 0} | 
                    Select-Object -Unique @{n="Server Name";e={$_.PSComputerName}}, 
                                          @{n="DNS Server";e={$_.ServerAddresses.split(',') -join ', '}};
    } Catch {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Server Name' = $machine
        'DNS Server'  = 'Unavailable'
        }
    }
};


The scripts work but when I come across a server that is on a different subnet or otherwise unreachable, I get a WinRM error. Which is fine but I need to log it. I have tried try & catch but cannot seem to export the error into the CSV. If it runs into that error, I would like it to write the server name in the CSV file and under the 'DNS Server' header, just say something like 'Communication Issue."

@user2623974 I just updated the answer with variation #5 and #6.... that's the only way I was able to work it out. Adjust accordingly for your needs with applicable other examples or whatever logic you are using. Let me know if there are difficulties otherwise. Happy to help further if needed.

I thought the solution would be something easy and straightforward that I just missed but I see now it was not as easy as I imagined. Well done!
